# Can I display the IE compatibility version of a HTA inside itself?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, version, compatibility, hta

So I've got this code that runs inside a HTA...

```
jsv=ScriptEngine()+' v'
    +ScriptEngineMajorVersion()+'.'
    +ScriptEngineMinorVersion()+'.'
    +ScriptEngineBuildVersion()
```

It displays the version of **JScript** the HTA is using.

### So...  My question is:

Can I display the **IE Compatibility Mode** version, or similar, of the HTA in the same way?

And if so... How?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE8 and later, you can retrieve [`document.documentMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It gives you a number representing the current document mode, `5` for quirks-mode, `6` for IE6 etc.

In IE6-7 there was [`document.combatMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which returned a string telling you whether the standards-compliant mode is switched on or not.

Notice, that `ScriptEngine` returns the latest available JScript version, the used document mode doesn't change the values.